# Compress / zip multiple files on google cloud storage without downloading

Tags: google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I want to compress / zip multiple files in google cloud storage bucket into single zip file without downloading them.

Is there any gsutil cli method which takes multiple path input and cp zip / compressed of all those input files.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, there's no functionality in GCS that supports this.  And if the API doesn't support it, no tools or client libraries can, as they're simply making API calls under the hood.

Answer (score -1):

Here it is, though not natively but you can host on ur machine or Google cloud for better
https://www.npmjs.com/package/zip-bucket